# Can Notepad read UTF-32?

Tags: unicode, windows-7, notepad, utf-32

These bytes represent the word "hi" in UTF-32LE:

```
FF FE 00 00 68 00 00 00 69 00 00 00
```

However this is what Notepad displays:

[image]

Comment: The BOM for UTF16LE is FF FE, also a match.  Having text files encoded in utf32 is exceedingly rare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad does not support UTF-32, only ANSI, UTF-8, and UTF-16.  It is interpreting the first 2 bytes as a UTF-16LE BOM, not the first 4 bytes as a UTF-32LE BOM, so the file bytes get interpreted as

`FF FE` `00 00` `68 00` `00 00` `69 00` `00 00`

Instead of

`FF FE 00 00` `68 00 00 00` `69 00 00 00`