# spring write string to file - spacing error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, file

In my *Spring boot* application, I receive `String`, now I want to save them as files in a specific directory.

How can I do so ?

I have gone through [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/), but it is receiving file and saving, but I want to write to those files.

I'm using this code, raw JAVA:

```
PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter("file.txt", "UTF_32");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writer.println(data);
        writer.close();
```

But it not how everyone will probably want, take a look:

[image: space in spring-error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's your character encoding, UTF_32.

Notepad does not support UTF_32, only ansi, UTF_8, UTF_16.

See:

[Can Notepad read UTF-32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536709/can-notepad-read-utf-32)